# ActiveX component can't create an object after MS patch update (KB4340558)

Tags: .net, asp-classic, windows-update

We are getting the below error after the successful installation of the latest 
Microsoft security patch (KB4340558).

```
*Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01ad'
```

ActiveX component can't create an object

/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/global.asa, line 14*

```
Set objASPConfig = Server.CreateObject("ASPConfig.ConnStringObj")
```

The above line of code throws the error. It’s trying to get `ASPConfig.dll` Is placed in Gac. while getting the connection string from the gac we are getting the ActiveX component can't create object error. After uninstalling the patch application started working

Comment: Just [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=ActiveX%20component%20can%27t), there's at least 4 in the last 2 days on this exact topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem here... but found the solution.

On "Authentication" option, on your web application, double click, select "Anonymous Authentication", click edit... If you have, "specific user " option selected, change it to "Application pool Identity."

[image]

Comment: Already explained here - [How do I properly instantiate 32-bit COM objects in classic ASP after installing Windows Update KB4340558?](//stackoverflow.com/a/51304586)

Comment: Thank you very much Marco, it helped me a lot :)

Comment: @KarthiKeyan so the existing answer wasn't helpful, or you not willing to acknowledge that may be this question wouldn't have been necessary if you just looked at the recent questions page?